# Rectangle doesn't draw

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently coding a game for university and I need a sidepanel for that. So I wanted to draw a rectangle on the side. Below you can see my code. We should just use PyGame for everything.

```
def drawRect():
    rect2 = pygame.Rect(SCREEN_WIDTH - PANEL_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT, PANEL_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, rect2)
```

The rectangle doesnt pop up on my screen and I just cant figure out why.

Comment: Please make sure the indentation of your code in your question is _identical_ to what is in your actual code, because python is sensitive to indentation errors. I prefer to use [code blocks](/help/formatting) with three backticks ( ` ) for this. Since you're new here, please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

In the *Pygame* coordinate system, the top left is (0, 0). Hence, the rectangle at the bottom is off the screen. Change the position of the rectangle:

<s>`rect2 = pygame.Rect(SCREEN_WIDTH - PANEL_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT, PANEL_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT)`</s>

```py
rect2 = pygame.Rect(SCREEN_WIDTH - PANEL_SIZE, 0, PANEL_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
```